# MUI-react installation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules

Im new to react and i want to install MUI library in my react but somehow it said like this

```
239 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Comment: If you are new to react, I wouldn't suggest you using MUI in a first place, because without understanding basic concepts, taking any react component library in use could be too overwhelming and will lead to a messy code. As for your question, there is nothing really wrong with installing the MUI, you can either try suggested command to fix those issues or just ignore them

Comment: thank you for answering,i did know the basic but i need the component library i cant make it my self im front end type